# Filter Comma and Whitespace in String using Regular Expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter a string using regular expression so that:

- multiple space is replaced with a single space
- all space before and after comma is replaced with single comma
- remove multiple comma with space
- remove staring and ending comma

---

**Sample Input:**

> " , This,  is A ,,, Test  , , to find regex,,in js 123  , "

---

**Expected Output:**

> "this,is a,test,to find regex,in js 123"

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I have came up with a solution that is working so far.

```js
var str = " , This, is A ,,, Test , , to find regex,,in js 123 , ";

str = str.replace(/ +/g, " "); //replace multiple space with single space
str = str.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ","); //replace space before and after comma with single comma
str = str.replace(/,+/g, ","); //remove multiple comma with single comma
str = str.replace(/^,|,$/g, ""); //remove starting and ending comma

console.log(str);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thx

Comment: I have just found a solution. It is provided below and want to optimize it further.

Comment: I edited your question, if you have the solution to your answer, post it below in the answers, if you have the code you have so far (which is not the answer), please edit your question and never add it as the answer. Thanks <3

Comment: I have approved your edit. It explains more elaborately. Thank you, @Stephan T.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all spaces next to commas:

```
replace(/ *, */g, ’,’)
```

Second, replace all consecutive commas with single commas and all consecutive spaces with single spaces:

```
replace(/,+/g, ‘,’)
replace(/ +/g, ‘ ‘)
```

Finally, remove leading and trailing commas:

```
replace(/^,/, ‘’)
replace(/,$/, ‘’)
```

```js
var str = " , This, is A ,,, Test , , to find regex,,in js 123 , ";
str = str.replace(/^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$|\s*(\s|,)[\s,]*/g, "$1");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: or maybe do it all in one step? `.replace(/^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$|\s*(\s|,)[\s,]*/g, "$1")`